# How can I make a border wrap around a group of pictures?

Tags: html, css, image, border

I'm trying to figure out how to make a border fit exactly around a group of images. As you can see in this [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Stuckurface/3TjLP/) I posted, the border fits around the top and left corner, but it doesn't fit exactly around the bottom and right corners.
Here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Gallery Test</title>
            <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="CSS.css"/>
        </head>
        <div class="album">
                <span><img class="img1" id="imgAlbum" src="http://images.nationalgeographic.com/wpf/media-live/photos/000/006/cache/red-                                      fox_679_600x450.jpg">
                </span>
                <span><img class="img2" id="imgAlbum" src="http://images.nationalgeographic.com/wpf/media-live/photos/000/006/cache/red-                                      fox_679_600x450.jpg">
                </span>
                <span><img class="img3" id="imgAlbum" src="http://images.nationalgeographic.com/wpf/media-live/photos/000/006/cache/red-                                      fox_679_600x450.jpg">
                </span>              
        </div>


</html>
```

And Here is my CSS:

```
.img1{
    border-width:4px;
    border-style:solid;
}
.img2 {
    position:relative;
    right: 90px;
    top:5px;
    z-index:-1;

    border-width:4px;
    border-style:solid;
}
.img3{
    position:relative;
    right:180px;
    top:10px;
    z-index:-2;

    border-width:4px;
    border-style:solid;
}
.album {
    border-width:2px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#78c9a9;
    display:inline-block;
}

#imgAlbum {
    height:150px;
    width:100px;
}
p {
    color:red;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you just trying to make the border line up with the bottom of the layered images or are you trying to make it line up with the right-hand side as well? http://jsfiddle.net/h88Ma/ Also, on your `<img>` tags, you have your `id`s and `class`es mixed up

Comment: I am trying to get it to line up with both  the bottom and right sides. Also, can you not use `class`es and `id`s in the same `<img>` tag?

Comment: You can use both classes and ids, but ids must be unique. You should never have the same id for multiple elements. That's what classes are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some errors in your CSS/HTML. I corrected them and floated the images so that the border raps them exactly. I also removed the `<span>` tag which was not used.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/3TjLP/3/)**

*HTML :*

```
    <div id="album">
        <img id="img1" class="imgAlbum" src="http://images.nationalgeographic.com/wpf/media-live/photos/000/006/cache/red-                                       fox_679_600x450.jpg" />
        <img id="img2" class="imgAlbum" src="http://images.nationalgeographic.com/wpf/media-live/photos/000/006/cache/red-                                      fox_679_600x450.jpg" />
        <img id="img3" class="imgAlbum" src="http://images.nationalgeographic.com/wpf/media-live/photos/000/006/cache/red-                                      fox_679_600x450.jpg" />                   
    </div>
```

*CSS :*

```
#img2 {
    z-index:-1;
    margin: 5px 0 0 -90px;
}
#img3{
    z-index:-2;
    margin: 10px 0 0 -80px;

}
#album {
    border-width:2px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#78c9a9;
    display:inline-block;
}

.imgAlbum {
    position:relative;
    height:150px;
    width:100px;
    border:4px solid #000;
    display:block;
    float:left;
}
p {
    color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using border-width use width and height of the album class which wraps your images.

```
.album {
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    display:inline-block;
    border : 2px #78c9a9 solid;
}
```

Comment: I've tried this before but the issue is when you change the width and height to that of the images, it screws up the image placement.

Comment: That is because the width of th images container is rigid unless if you make the width auto then it will increase the moment you change the size or the number of images

Answer (score 0):

If you use **negative** `margin` insread `relative` positionning, the area used by img is reduced.
When you use relative + coordonate, space used by img remains the same, you only see it at another position. **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3TjLP/4/)**

Some Infos on **[W3C WIKI](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS_static_and_relative_positioning#Relative_positioning)**

---

for img(inline-boxe) you may use `vertical-align` instead vertical coordonates : **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3TjLP/5/)**

`Position:relative` remains usefull for triggering z-index properies.

```
.img1{
    border-width:4px;
    border-style:solid;
}
.img2 {
    position:relative;
    margin-left: -90px;
    vertical-align:-5px;
    z-index:-1;
    border-width:4px;
    border-style:solid;
}
.img3{
    position:relative;
   margin-left: -90px;
    vertical-align:-10px;
    z-index:-2;

    border-width:4px;
    border-style:solid;
}
.album {
    border-width:2px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#78c9a9;
    display:inline-block;
}

#imgAlbum {
    height:150px;
    width:100px;
}
p {
    color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**[JSFiddle example using margins](http://jsfiddle.net/JPLvJ/)**

HTML:

```
<div class="album">
  <div class="imgAlbum"><img src="http://images.nationalgeographic.com/wpf/media-live/photos/000/006/cache/red-fox_679_600x450.jpg" /></div>
  <div class="imgAlbum"><img src="http://images.nationalgeographic.com/wpf/media-live/photos/000/006/cache/red-fox_679_600x450.jpg" /></div>
  <div class="imgAlbum"><img src="http://images.nationalgeographic.com/wpf/media-live/photos/000/006/cache/red-fox_679_600x450.jpg" /></div>              
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box /* so that borders don't affect our box measurements */
}
.album {
  border: 2px solid #78c9a9;
  display: inline-block;
}
.imgAlbum {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 7rem; /* common size    */
  width: 10rem; /* for all images */
  position: relative; /* for z-index mostly */
  margin-left: -9rem; /* offset for each child */
  vertical-align: top;
}
.imgAlbum:nth-of-type(1) { /* first image shoud not be offset */
  margin-left: 0;
}
.imgAlbum:nth-of-type(2) {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  z-index: -1;
}
.imgAlbum:nth-of-type(3) {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  z-index: -2;
}
.imgAlbum img {
  width: 100%; height: 100%; /* scale images to .imgAlbum size */
  border: 3px solid black;
}
```